# Definition of parabolic matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is *unimodular* $2\times 2$ matrix, what is the meaning of saying "If $A$ is parabolic..."? Is that when characteristic polynomial of $A$ is with degree of $2$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unimodular matrices of size $2$, $A$ is called parabolic, if $|tr (A)|=2$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2%28R%29.